# react-snap removing api key from build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snipcart, react-snap

I am using react-snap to pre-render my site and in my `index.html` file I have the code below

```
<div id="snipcart" data-api-key="key"></div>
```

however it outputs the code as below

```
<div id="snipcart" class="snipcart"><!----><!----></div>
```

How can I change it so it outputs correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending the data-api-key value for Snipcart w/vue meta in gridsome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634842/sending-the-data-api-key-value-for-snipcart-w-vue-meta-in-gridsome)

Answer (score 0):

That's Snipcart itself which is replacing the div.

If you have an issue with your cart integration, it is most certainly something else.